# Mass-energy equation - The units

Tags: units, mass-energy

We know that $E=mc^2$ and we use the units from the international system of units instead of the values we get, $\rm J=kg\cdot m/s$. From what I've been taught, I know that momentum is using the $\rm kg\cdot m/s$ units.

Considering both are true. Why isn't the mass-energy equation, mass-momentum equation due to the units used in them?

Comment: ${\rm J}\equiv {\rm kg\cdot m^2/s^2}$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_energy))

Comment: The little number ${}^2$ above $c$ means that it is squared. $E=m\times c\times c$ so the unit of energy is $[\mathrm{ kg.m^2.s^{-2}}]$.

Comment: Despite that typo, it is never a good method to equate properties purely from their units. Several properties have equal units but are fundamentally different, for example torque and energy.

Answer (score 1):

You just simply didn't do the math correctly. $E = mc^2$ expressed as dimensional units would be, $J = kg \cdot (m/s)^2$ which would equal, $J=kg\cdot m^2/s^2$, these are the SI base units of energy.

Answer (score 0):

We call it a [mass-energy equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence) because the rest-frame equation you cite relates mass ($m$), energy ($E$) & speed of light ($c$) in a single equation.

In particle physics, we often use [units where $c=1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units#%22Natural_units%22_(particle_physics_and_cosmology)) (simply to make things 'easier' to not have a whole bunch of $c$'s lying about), so we can then see that the equivalence relation is simply $E=m$ in these units, which shows clearly that it's a mass-energy relationship, not a mass-momentum one.

While [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) that you're using has its uses, simply ignoring the equation for the units itself is not particularly useful.